# How to set and access local parameters when launching a nodelet?

Tags: ros, parameter, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know how to set and read local a parameter using a plain node with

```
"_param:=value"
```

on the command line and

```
string value;
ros::param::get("~param", value)
```

To get the value in the code. But all my attempts to do so with a nodelet fail.

I need to add a local parameter to a nodelet I start. I though I need to add it to the `my_argv` parameter:

```
nodelet::M_string remappings;
nodelet::V_string my_argv;
my_argv.push_back("_param:=foo");
manager.load("NodeletName", "my_namespace/NodeletClassName", remappings, my_argv);
```

And in the nodelet, after `onInit()` in some callback I have:

```
std::string param;
ros::param::get("~param", param);
std::cout << "param = " << param << "." << std::endl;
```

Which prints `param = .`. I also tried `getPrivateNodeHandle().getParam("param", param)` with no success.

I guess I'm doing it completely wrong?

The background is, that I want to start load multiple nodelets of the same type but with different configurations. Perhaps there is some other canonical way for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218007/how-to-set-and-access-local-parameters-when-launching-a-nodelet?/) by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 789 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-09-23**:
When I launch the same nodelet with in a launch file, I am able to set the arguments using `args="_param:=value"` and the read them using `getPrivateNodeHandle().getParam("param", param)`. Perhaps thats engough for me, but I still wonder how it would be possible with roscpp nodlet loader only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To pass a parameter value to a nodelet, try either passing it as an argument on the command line when you run the executable that loads the nodelet (i.e. "_param:=value") or set the parameter using ros::param::set("~param", value).

In either case the nodelet should be able to access it using getPrivateNodeHandle().getParam("param", value).

---

Originally posted by [dseifert](https://answers.ros.org/users/24478/dseifert/) with karma: 106 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2015-10-17**:
The thing is I want to start multiple nodelets with the same executable with different parameters. If I run ros::param::set(...) I'm setting the parameter for all those those nodelets, don't I?

**Comment by [dseifert](https://answers.ros.org/users/24478/dseifert/) on 2015-10-20**:
I would assume each nodelet is in a different namespace, and so would be the parameters.